# How to store different line numbers from file into a set?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, visual-c++, set

I'm trying to get words from a text file and store it as the key value of a map, and as for the value, a set containing the different lines in which each word appears in the file. I don't have a clear idea how to get line numbers from each word and store it in a set. The code I have so far is the following.

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    string word;
    vector<string> list;
    set<int> lines;
    int linecount = 0;
    myfile.open("kennedy.txt");
    if (myfile.fail()) {
        cout << "No file found";
    }
    else
        while (myfile >> word) {
            list.push_back(word);
        }
    for (auto element : list)
        cout << element << endl;

    map<string, int> word1 = {{list.at(0),/*set*/} };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    string word;
    int linecount = 1;
    set<int> lines; //the default set, which we use only to initialize
    map<string, set<int>> wordmap;

    myfile.open("kennedy.txt");
    if (!myfile) { //if an error happened. Same as myfile.fail(), myfile.bad(), and myfile.eof() combined.
        cout << "No file found";
    }
     //no need for the else that was here before
    while (getline(myfile, word)) { //for each line
        stringstream wordstream;
        wordstream << word; //put the line into a stringstream
        while (wordstream >> word) { //for every word we get out of wordstream
            if (!wordmap.count(word)) wordmap.insert({ word, lines }); //if it is not in our map, add it with the default set
            auto current = wordmap.find(word); //get an iterator to the word
            current->second.insert(linecount); //add the current line to the word's set of ints
        }
        ++linecount; //increment the linecount
    }

    //Example of how to access the elements:

    for (auto element : wordmap) {
        cout << "Key: " << element.first << " Values: ";
        for (int item : element.second) {
            cout << item << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

The comments pretty much explain what I did.

I tested this with text copy/pasted from https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/13/level-up-creative-coding-with-p5-js-parts-4-and-5/?cb=1&_ga=2.159343934.584816135.1618070092-708873185.1600384169. The .txt file looked like this:

```
Level Up: Creative Coding with p5.js – parts 4 and 5
Part 4 In this session, we will make our p5.js sketches interactive! Together with Morgan, we will work on the Generative Art Creator project using the p5.js web editor! We will make a tool to create, control, and combine generative works of art inspired by early media artists, such as John Whitney and Vera Molnar.…
Avatar for 
Jiwon Shin
Part 4
In this session, we will make our p5.js sketches interactive! Together with Morgan, we will work on the Generative Art Creator project using the p5.js web editor! We will make a tool to create, control, and combine generative works of art inspired by early media artists, such as John Whitney and Vera Molnar. We will map different visualizations to be triggered by each key on the keyboard.


Here are some Stack Overflow questions related to the work we did in this session:

How to trigger key events in p5.js

How to make something happen when a key is held down in p5.js

How do I hold down a key in p5 instead of just pressing it repeatedly?

How do I save a p5.js canvas as a very large PNG?

If you enjoyed this lesson, you can catch up on the rest of the series on YouTube. If you’d like to watch a session live, follow the Codecademy YouTube channel.

Every Tuesday from now until April 27th, we’ll be streaming a new session at 4PM EST. You can set a reminder for the stream for April 6th here.

Finally, if you want even more Creative Coding with p5.js content, you can sign up for the interactive course this series was based on here. This course was developed by Jiwon and has many more quizzes, projects, and helpful articles that we can’t fit into our streams!

Part 5
In this session, we will learn how to display and manipulate images and videos in our p5.js sketches. Together, we will work on the Interactive Video Sculpture project using the p5.js web editor! We will create a digital video sculpture inspired by the artist Nam Jun Paik. Applying what we learned in our last session, we’ll also add mouse interaction to dynamically change the videos displayed in the sculpture.


Here are some Stack Overflow questions related to the work we did in this session:

p5.js Play Video inside canvas

Stretch a video in p5.js?

If you enjoyed this lesson, you can catch up on the rest of the series on YouTube. If you’d like to watch a session live, follow the Codecademy YouTube channel.

Every Tuesday from now until April 27th, we’ll be streaming a new session at 4PM EST. You can set a reminder for the stream for April 13th here.

Finally, if you want even more Creative Coding with p5.js content, you can sign up for the interactive course this series was based on here. This course was developed by Jiwon and has many more quizzes, projects, and helpful articles that we can’t fit into our streams!

Tags: codeacademy, creative coding, level up, p5.js
```

The output was:

```
Key: 13th Values: 38
Key: 27th, Values: 22 38
Key: 4 Values: 2 3 6
Key: 4PM Values: 22 38
Key: 5 Values: 2 26
Key: 6th Values: 22
Key: Applying Values: 27
Key: April Values: 22 38
Key: Art Values: 3 7
Key: Avatar Values: 4
Key: Codecademy Values: 20 36
Key: Coding Values: 2 24 40
Key: Creative Values: 2 24 40
Key: Creator Values: 3 7
Key: EST. Values: 22 38
Key: Every Values: 22 38
Key: Finally, Values: 24 40
Key: Generative Values: 3 7
Key: Here Values: 10 30
Key: How Values: 12 14 16 18
Key: I Values: 16 18
Key: If Values: 20 36
Key: In Values: 3 7 27
Key: Interactive Values: 27
Key: Jiwon Values: 5 24 40
Key: John Values: 3 7
Key: Jun Values: 27
Key: Level Values: 2
Key: Molnar. Values: 7
Key: Molnar.ΓÇª Values: 3
Key: Morgan, Values: 3 7
Key: Nam Values: 27
Key: Overflow Values: 10 30
Key: PNG? Values: 18
Key: Paik. Values: 27
Key: Part Values: 3 6 26
Key: Play Values: 32
Key: Sculpture Values: 27
Key: Shin Values: 5
Key: Stack Values: 10 30
Key: Stretch Values: 34
Key: Tags: Values: 42
Key: This Values: 24 40
Key: Together Values: 3 7
Key: Together, Values: 27
Key: Tuesday Values: 22 38
Key: Up: Values: 2
Key: Vera Values: 3 7
Key: Video Values: 27 32
Key: We Values: 3 7 27
Key: Whitney Values: 3 7
Key: You Values: 22 38
Key: YouTube Values: 20 36
Key: YouTube. Values: 20 36
Key: a Values: 3 7 14 16 18 20 22 27 34 36 38
Key: add Values: 27
Key: also Values: 27
Key: and Values: 2 3 7 24 27 40
Key: are Values: 10 30
Key: art Values: 3 7
Key: articles Values: 24 40
Key: artist Values: 27
Key: artists, Values: 3 7
Key: as Values: 3 7 18
Key: at Values: 22 38
Key: based Values: 24 40
Key: be Values: 7 22 38
Key: by Values: 3 7 24 27 40
Key: can Values: 20 22 24 36 38 40
Key: canvas Values: 18 32
Key: canΓÇÖt Values: 24 40
Key: catch Values: 20 36
Key: change Values: 27
Key: channel. Values: 20 36
Key: codeacademy, Values: 42
Key: coding, Values: 42
Key: combine Values: 3 7
Key: content, Values: 24 40
Key: control, Values: 3 7
Key: course Values: 24 40
Key: create Values: 27
Key: create, Values: 3 7
Key: creative Values: 42
Key: developed Values: 24 40
Key: did Values: 10 30
Key: different Values: 7
Key: digital Values: 27
Key: display Values: 27
Key: displayed Values: 27
Key: do Values: 16 18
Key: down Values: 14 16
Key: dynamically Values: 27
Key: each Values: 7
Key: early Values: 3 7
Key: editor! Values: 3 7 27
Key: enjoyed Values: 20 36
Key: even Values: 24 40
Key: events Values: 12
Key: fit Values: 24 40
Key: follow Values: 20 36
Key: for Values: 4 22 24 38 40
Key: from Values: 22 38
Key: generative Values: 3 7
Key: happen Values: 14
Key: has Values: 24 40
Key: held Values: 14
Key: helpful Values: 24 40
Key: here. Values: 22 24 38 40
Key: hold Values: 16
Key: how Values: 27
Key: if Values: 24 40
Key: images Values: 27
Key: in Values: 10 12 14 16 27 30 34
Key: inside Values: 32
Key: inspired Values: 3 7 27
Key: instead Values: 16
Key: interaction Values: 27
Key: interactive Values: 24 40
Key: interactive! Values: 3 7
Key: into Values: 24 40
Key: is Values: 14
Key: it Values: 16
Key: just Values: 16
Key: key Values: 7 12 14 16
Key: keyboard. Values: 7
Key: large Values: 18
Key: last Values: 27
Key: learn Values: 27
Key: learned Values: 27
Key: lesson, Values: 20 36
Key: level Values: 42
Key: like Values: 20 36
Key: live, Values: 20 36
Key: make Values: 3 7 14
Key: manipulate Values: 27
Key: many Values: 24 40
Key: map Values: 7
Key: media Values: 3 7
Key: more Values: 24 40
Key: mouse Values: 27
Key: new Values: 22 38
Key: now Values: 22 38
Key: of Values: 3 7 16 20 36
Key: on Values: 3 7 20 24 27 36 40
Key: our Values: 3 7 24 27 40
Key: p5 Values: 16
Key: p5.js Values: 2 3 7 12 14 18 24 27 32 40 42
Key: p5.js? Values: 34
Key: parts Values: 2
Key: pressing Values: 16
Key: project Values: 3 7 27
Key: projects, Values: 24 40
Key: questions Values: 10 30
Key: quizzes, Values: 24 40
Key: related Values: 10 30
Key: reminder Values: 22 38
Key: repeatedly? Values: 16
Key: rest Values: 20 36
Key: save Values: 18
Key: sculpture Values: 27
Key: sculpture. Values: 27
Key: series Values: 20 24 36 40
Key: session Values: 20 22 36 38
Key: session, Values: 3 7 27
Key: session: Values: 10 30
Key: set Values: 22 38
Key: sign Values: 24 40
Key: sketches Values: 3 7
Key: sketches. Values: 27
Key: some Values: 10 30
Key: something Values: 14
Key: stream Values: 22 38
Key: streaming Values: 22 38
Key: streams! Values: 24 40
Key: such Values: 3 7
Key: that Values: 24 40
Key: the Values: 3 7 10 20 22 24 27 30 36 38 40
Key: this Values: 3 7 10 20 24 27 30 36 40
Key: to Values: 3 7 10 12 14 20 27 30 36
Key: tool Values: 3 7
Key: trigger Values: 12
Key: triggered Values: 7
Key: until Values: 22 38
Key: up Values: 20 24 36 40
Key: up, Values: 42
Key: using Values: 3 7 27
Key: very Values: 18
Key: video Values: 27 34
Key: videos Values: 27
Key: visualizations Values: 7
Key: want Values: 24 40
Key: was Values: 24 40
Key: watch Values: 20 36
Key: we Values: 3 7 10 24 27 30 40
Key: web Values: 3 7 27
Key: weΓÇÖll Values: 22 27 38
Key: what Values: 27
Key: when Values: 14
Key: will Values: 3 7 27
Key: with Values: 2 3 7 24 40
Key: work Values: 3 7 10 27 30
Key: works Values: 3 7
Key: you Values: 20 24 36 40
```

Note: I accidentally had an enter on the first line, so the values are one after

Answer (score -1):

I believe this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>

const char* text = 
"yellow red blue\n"
"blue blue\n"
"\n"
"red yellow blue\n"
"red blue\n";

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::set<size_t>> words;
    
    std::stringstream ss(text); // or replace by a std::ifstream
    std::string line;
    for (size_t l{0}; std::getline(ss, line); l++) {
        std::stringstream lineStream (line);
        for (std::string word; std::getline(lineStream, word, ' '); ) {
            // probably some work to do on 'word' here.
            // e.g. what happens with "blue.", "Blue" or "blueblue"? 
            words[word].insert(l);
        }
    }

    for (auto const& kv: words) {
        std::cout << "> " << kv.first << ": ";
        for (auto const& w: kv.second) std::cout << w << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4b6Mvn

Output:

```
> blue: 0 1 3 4 
> red: 0 3 4 
> yellow: 0 3
```

Comment: Instead of giving a block of code as answer, can you elaborate on what was the error, and what you fixed, in text?

Comment: I mean, I can elaborate if OP has questions, but they just asked "how to do X" not "I don't understand how X works".

Comment: What the OP wants is irrelevant. This site is a Q and A site. Q and A only have value so far as they are questions and answers :-)

Comment: Sometimes 8 lines of codes with a few comments is enough of an answer. "Show, don't tell".

Comment: For example, you could post your own answer instead of patronizing me on how to answer. :-)

Comment: I appreciate your code but i can hardly read any of that, i'm only a first year cs student. I tried it out, but it threw me 20 errors, and even with a bit of tampering no luck. Thanks though

Comment: @sidereal I edited it so it's C++11 compatible. It's not a long code though. Check [std::stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get a sense  of what they're doing. Basically: `ss` stores the whole text and `getline` reads from it line by line (using `\n` as a delimiter). Then a 2nd `getline` separates each word in the line (using a ` ` delimiter this time). Finally ,we store each line number  where it belongs.